# Executing csv.file with mongolite in R on Mac

Tags: r, mongodb, csv, mongolite

I successfully ran the basic query, and it worked well.

```
m<- mongo(collection = "airlines_Mon", db = "airlines_Mon", url = "mongodb://localhost",
verbose = TRUE,options = ssl_options())
m$insert(airlines_Mon)
airlines_Mon1 = m$find('{}')
head(airlines_Mon1)
```

I got the following result

```
head(airlines_Mon1)
      V1                     V2
1 carrier                   name
2      9E      Endeavor Air Inc.
3      AA American Airlines Inc.
4      AS   Alaska Airlines Inc.
5      B6        JetBlue Airways
6      DL   Delta Air Lines Inc.
```

Then I tried to retrieve certain parts of the data like

```
m$find( '{ "carrier": "UA" }' )
```

And I got the following result

```
Imported 0 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
```

Does anyone know why? Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: It doesn't appear that 'carrier' is the name of an object. You can see this by it being in the first row of your data, rather than the column heading.

Comment: @SymbolixAU thanks! do you know how can I change it to the column name by chance?

Comment: what does `airlines_Mon` look like? can you update / edit your question with the output of `dput(head(airlines_Mon))`